# Calling an function expression with a name outside

Tags: javascript, function-expression

I have function expression in javascript like this:

```
(function () {
    .
    //code here
    .
    .
}());
```

how do I call it from somewhere else like from another function.

I have tried this.

```
var bind = (function () {
    //code here...//
}());
```

and called it in some other function like

```
bind();
```

or

```
new bind();
```

or

```
var b = new bind();
```

but it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: `var bind = function() { // code here }; bind();`

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work.`?

Comment: the function doesn't get executed :P

Answer (score 0):

With this statement:

```
var bind = (function () {
    //code here...//

    return 42;
}());
```

`bind` variable is not assigned to that function. Instead, it is assigned with the returned value of the immediate function. So you will get `bind = 42`.

**To define a function with immediate function**

You may want to create a function inside the immediate function (which may compose a closure if you want) and returns it for later use. See the example below:

```
var bind = (function() {
    function B(){
        // do something
        return 42;
    }
    return B;
}());

bind(); // <-----bind is a B(), so invoke it will return 42
```

This will potentially create a function from the immediate function and assigns it the the `bind` variable so you can invoke it later.